# RazorMachine: The type or namespace name 'HelperResult' could not be found

Tags: .net, razor

Try to use simple func:

`var E = (Func<object, HelperResult>)(
        (object obj) => {
            this.WriteLiteral("font-weight=\"bold\"");
            return new HelperResult(tw => { });
        });
}`

with [RazorMachine](https://github.com/jlamfers/RazorMachine), but got next error:

`compile error: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HelperResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Is there any chance to use `Html` or `HelperResult` in compiled templates?

Comment: You need to go into your Views folder and add the namespace to your web.config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found the answer:

```
List<string> ns = new List<string>() { 
  "System.Web.Mvc", 
  "System.Web.Mvc.Html", 
  "System.Web.WebPages"
};
var machine = new RazorMachine(namespaces: ns);
```

RazorMachine has constructor argument named `namespaces`, where you could pass missing namespaces.